# How to configure DHCP for wireless clients on TP-Link N Modem Router?

Tags: networking, router, wifi, dhcp-server

I have a TP-Link TD-8961ND Wireless N ADSL2+ modem router with which I would like to deploy wireless internet in a meeting room.

The Internet source is an Ethernet cable which I connect to one of the LAN ports of the router and then use the router as access point to distribute Internet by wi-fi. The network signal comes into the room through a wall socket (RJ-45), into which I connect a TP-Link desktop switch, which is in turn connected to the wireless router. (This is the available equipment and I have to find a solution using these)

I initially tried a basic configuration just to see how the clients received the signal and everything went great. By basic configuration I mean, simply configuring the SSID and a static address from the incoming local network as ISP address. The clients all connected to the wireless signal and had Internet access. The main problem here being that it entails me always being available to configure static address details for the wireless network on each connected client before they can have Internet.

For this reason, I decided to go for a DHCP configuration by which any client which connects to the wireless router will have its IP configuration automatically set for use. This is where my problem lies.

I have been trying for many hours now, have dug through the web in search for a solution, I'm unable to configure the DHCP service on the router. Each time I enable DHCP (by checking "Enabled" from **Interface -> Interface Setup -> LAN -> DHCP**) and save, the page just stares at me, no reaction. I have tried changing the IP address and starting IP address for the pool to no effect.
I tried using different browsers, still no difference.
I even tried tweaking lots of other parameters: Bridge Mode for Encapsulation (instead of static address from incoming network), router local IP as default private address or as an address from the incoming network (when bridge mode enabled), and many other little pointless changes. No good!

Please, can anyone help me out here? Is what I'm trying to do even possible at all?

Comment: Sounds like this might be more complicated than it needs to be. The router should be turned in to a basic AP or “bridge.” This is done by simply disabling DHCP and plugging your internet feed into a LAN port (Nothing should be plugged in to a WAN port)., then configuring your WiFi settings. In this mode the router becomes a basic bridge between the wired LAN and the WiFi clients. Clients will get an IP from whatever device hands out IP addresses on the rest of your network.

Comment: You got it right, I'm using the router as bridge and AP and the Internet feed comes in through LAN port. Like I explained above, I initially tried basic WiFi settings to test my set-up and everything was OK. My issue now is for WiFi clients to get their IP addresses through DHCP from the router (it would be painstaking for me to have to go around and manually configure static addresses each time the meeting room is used). All other devices on the network (workstations, printers, etc) use static addressing. Maybe it just isn't possible to do what I'm trying?

Comment: It’s not possible to do that in this way. Why are you running static IP addresses on everything? If you enable DHCP on this router it will handout IP addresses to any device on the entire network. You would have to segregate the network and use it as a router - internet plugs in to the WAN port.

Comment: I met the network configured that way for static addressing and I don't have the required access and permission to change the configurations on the main router (for example, to change to dynamic addressing). I also think it was configured for static addressing for security reasons, so as to be able to precisely identify every piece of equipement on the network. However, I've asked for temporary exceptions as concerns the meeting room, otherwise address management would be unnecessarily time- and energy-consuming each time the meeting room is used.

Comment: Yes, sounds like the right track. You can use static IP addresses on the devices you want, but still provide DHCP services for devices that come and go. Not providing any DHCP services is just stupid and feels like 1980. Whoever is in control of those settings needs a bit of a refresher course.

Comment: Haha 1980 indeed, if only you knew! (Not too surprising in this part of the world). I would certainly try your suggestion: segregate the network and use the router as a router, so it dynamically attributes addresses to the WIFi clients. Maybe that's the reason why my previous configuration wasn't accepted in the first place. However, since the incoming network has addresses on a particular range and a proxy server, I guess I would also need to configure NAT with the modem router's address so that the wireless clients all access the Internet with the router's WAN-side address... right?

Comment: Yes, you would use NAT for devices connected behind the router you are adding.

Comment: Actually, I realised that the WAN port is an ADSL port (into which the Ethernet cable used to bring the incoming signal into the room can't be plugged). Beside that, I'm only left with the LAN ports! I guess what I'm trying to do will not be possible after all. I'll probably have to stick to static addressing of all potential WiFi clients, sadly.